# Does MATLAB support the parallelization of supervised machine learning algorithms? Alternatives?

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing, data-mining, multicore, rapidminer

Up to now I have used RapidMiner for some data/text mining tasks, but with an increasing amount of data there are huge performance issues. AFAIK the RapidMiner Parallel Processing Extensions is only available for the enterprise version - unfortunately I am limited to the community version.

Now I want to transfer the tasks to a high performance cluster by using MATLAB (academic license). I did not find any information that the Parallel Computation Toolbox supports e.g. SVM or KNN.

Does MATLAB or any additional libraries support the paralleliization of data mining algorithms?

Comment: How about using the well-known parallel processing frameworks, like Vowpal Wabbit, Spark, Mahout, H2O, Oryx, etc.? The community edition of rapidminer is several years old. **I would avoid locking yourself in into MATLAB**. Their licenses are darn expensive, and your students will not be able to use it on their laptops anymore.

Comment: If there was no problem regarding the MATLAB licenses, would you still prefer the other frameworks?

Comment: Yes. I believe in open source, and open research. Few will use your research unless you make it available to everybody as open source, for open platforms. It's exactly why R and Python are on the rise, and MATLAB is declining.

Answer (score 1):

Most data mining and machine learning functionality for MATLAB is contained within Statistics Toolbox (in recent versions, that's called Statistics and Machine Learning Toolbox). To enable parallelization, you'll also need Parallel Computing Toolbox, and to enable that parallelization to be carried out on an HPC cluster, you'll need to install MATLAB Distributed Computing Server on the cluster.

There are lots of ways that you might want to parallelize data mining tasks - for example, you might want to parallelize an individual learning task, or parallelize a cross-validation, or parallelize several learning tasks across multiple datasets.

The first is possible for some, but not all of the data mining algorithms in Statistics Toolbox. MathWorks are gradually introducing that piece by piece. For example, `kmeans` is parallelized, and there is a parallelized algorithm for bagged decision trees, but I believe SVM learning is currently not parallelized. You'll need to look into the documentation for Statistics Toolbox to find out if the algorithms you require are on the list.

The second two are possible. Functionality in Statistics Toolbox for cross-validation (and bootstrapping, jack-knifing) is parallelized, as are some feature selection algorithms. And in order to parallelize running several jobs over multiple datasets, you can use functionality from Parallel Computing Toolbox (such as a `parfor` or parallel for loop) to iterate over them.

In addition, the upcoming R2015b release of MATLAB (out in September) will include GPU-enabled statistics functionality, providing additional speedups.

Comment: Bagged decision trees are supervised.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed response! The problem is that no supervised machine learning algorithm is parallelized within MATLAB (kmeans belongs to unsupervised machine learning algorithms) - http://de.mathworks.com/help/stats/quick-start-parallel-computing-for-statistics-toolbox.html. So, unfortunately parallelizing an individual learning task doesn't seem to be possible in the near future with MATLAB. Are there any libraries which support the paralellizing of individual learning tasks? Are there any other applications which support it?